# Validate a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I know how to use the Validating Event of the controls inside my form, but I don't want them to get validated when they loose focus because the ErrorProvider shows up and it looks messy. If the user just clicks on another control, the control that just lost focus gets marked red.

To solve this behaviour, I would like to validate the form when the user clicks on the OK-Button. Then all the controls that are invalid get marked red.
How should I be validating this form?

Comment: To validate when you click a button, just perform your validation login in the button's `Click` event.

Comment: If you select all controls in the designer and set their 'causesvalidation' property to false, validation will not occur while switching between those control, then in the button you can validate the entire form at once

Comment: Oh well... easy as that. I tought there was an other way. Thanks anyways.